# How to handle Firebase error messages for versions 17.0.1 and 16.0.1

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, build.gradle

I am currently working with Cloud Firestore as well as Cloud Storage and I keep getting these error messages right after adding the necessary dependencies to my app:

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-firestore-15.0.0
Failed to resolve: firebase-storage-15.0.0
Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0
```

I am pretty sure I have to fix the code lines but I don't know which part I have to edit:

[image]

Comment: @Dee Remove `:15.0.0` from the end of each dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the following errors:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-firestore-15.0.0
>
> Failed to resolve: firebase-storage-15.0.0
>
> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Because you are using a wrong dependencies in your code. To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Because such a versions `16.0.1:15.0.0` do **not** exist.

Please also add the following dependency which is now mandatory:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! But why does Firebase keep adding these flawed dependencies in Android? I did it several times now and it keeps happening.

Comment: In my opinion it's best to add those dependency manually not using tools.